# How to activate Twitter Bootstrap Tabs manually

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap

Using Twitter Bootstrap's [Tabbable Tabs][1], it says to:

"Enable tabbable tabs via javascript (each tab needs to be activated individually)":

```
  $('#myTab a').click(function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();
  $(this).tab('show');
   })
```

and then you can "*activate individual tabs in several ways"*:

```
$('#myTab a[href="#profile"]').tab('show'); // Select tab by name
$('#myTab a:first').tab('show'); // Select first tab
$('#myTab a:last').tab('show'); // Select last tab
$('#myTab li:eq(2) a').tab('show'); // Select third tab (0-indexed)
```

How could I activate each tab individually when I click in it and have it's #id appear in the URL?

Comment: The question is not clear. To activate the tab manually - just click on it

Comment: I'm wondering what code to use to show each tab #ID content in both the DIV section and the url after I've clicked on a tab

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is to add hash in url you can add this:

```
$('a').click(function(e){

e.preventDefault();
if(window.location.hash) window.location.hash = '';
window.location.hash = $(e.target).attr('class'); //or id, or other attribute

});
```

when user click on 'a' tag (or your tab id or etc...) then remove previus hash and append new hash.
basically use window.location.hash.

Comment: Thanks Alex...would you be available to chat? I'm really stuck on the whole reason I was trying to accomplish this.

Answer (score 0):

The way to have the hash show up correctly in the location url is **remove** the `e.preventDefault();` line. I'm assuming your A tags are pointing to #hash_tags like such: `<a href="#mytasks">My Tasks</a>`. Here is an example of how I activate bootstrap tabs using jQuery:

```
$('#tabs li a').each(function () {
  $(this).click(function (e) {
    $(this).tab("show");
  });
});
```