# Activate tabs with jQuery

Tags: jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I have a system to create, delete and rename tabs using jQuery. I am trying to set it up so that when a new tab is created it activates that tab but nothing seems to be working. I have tried the Tab API on the Twitter Bootstrap page but it does not seem to work.

jsFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/BenedictLewis/eYePA/

What I have tried:

```
$('#myTab a[href="#profile"]').tab('show'); // Select tab by name
$('#myTab a:first').tab('show'); // Select first tab
$('#myTab a:last').tab('show'); // Select last tab
$('#myTab li:eq(2) a').tab('show'); // Select third tab (0-indexed)
```

Comment: Looks remarkably similar to http://stackoverflow.com/q/11150505/139010...

Comment: @MattBall If you read the questions they are actually different.

Comment: @MattBall I did look though that question to see if there was an answer but I could not find one.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Short version - you forgot to add `id` to the link. That is why `$('#tab' + tabCount).tab('show');` doesn't work.

If you change line 5 to

```
.append($('<li><a href="#tab' + tabCount + '" id="tablnk' + tabCount + '" data-toggle="tab">New Page ' + tabCount + ' <i class="icon-remove tab-remove"></i></a></li>'));
```

and line 8 to

```
$('#tablnk' + tabCount).tab('show');
```

it works fine.

Comment: Awesome, I thought it might be something stupidly simple like that :)